# Admob xml errors

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I have made an app that used adMob ads before, but for some reason it wont work with my latest app.  The app works fine until I put in my xml coding.

I added the external JAR:

I added the code to the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
        android:value="a1504053602839f" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

I changed my target in the .properties to -14:

I also added this code to the top of my xml layouts:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

This is the code I use for the actual ad:

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a150072b02930f"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Like I said, I had this exact code working a month ago with my other app.

when I paste my ads.AdView code in my xml, the app wont even start up.  Once I cut the code out the app runs fine with no ads.
Also there are no ads in my Startup class, only the Game class.  But as soon as I startup the app it crashes regardless.

any suggestions?

Comment: what's the log ? And what do you need the meta-data balise ? that work s without

Comment: A log of the crash would be helpful.  My guess is that you haven't properly linked the AdMob library - you may have referenced it externally but didn't Export it.  Make sure to place the library inside the libs/ folder of your app. Also, it looks like your adUnitId in XML is only 14 characters long - it should probably be 15.  That doesn't explain the crash, but once you get it working you won't see ads if that adUnitId is in fact incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use meta-data in order to get add from admob so i could not tell you if error reside on meta-data, other wise your code is perfect.

You can check the jar you added, may be that is corrupt or no idea. You can use this code and can check if it work in your app

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <!-- Track Market installs from AdMob ads -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.ads.InstallReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Lay out --

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tbl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adddd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a14fe2bc0ebbc0c"
        ads:backgroundColor="#FFFF00"
        ads:keywords="SNS"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        ads:refreshInterval="30"
        ads:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</TableRow>
```